# Trying to get the data from database and load it into datatable got exception

Tags: c#, datatable, datarow

I am trying to get the database values and binding to data table by using the following query

```
sql = @"SELECT member_Id, 30*memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod  / DateDiff(memberToMship_EndDate, 
         memberToMship_StartDate) As monthlyamount,
         PERIOD_DIFF(DATE_FORMAT(now(),'%Y%m'), 
         DATE_FORMAT(memberToMship_StartDate,'%Y%m'))  + (DAY(memberToMship_StartDate) < memberToMship_DueDay)+ (DAY(now()) > memberToMship_DueDay)-1  AS ExpPayments, 
         SUM(memberToMship_InductionFee+memberToMship_JoinFee+
             (IF(mshipOption_Period='year',
             TIMESTAMPDIFF (YEAR ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate),
             TIMESTAMPDIFF (MONTH ,memberToMship_StartDate, memberToMship_EndDate)) * memberToMship_ChargePerPeriod)) as value 
        FROM membertomships 
        INNER JOIN mshipoptions on membertomships.mshipOption_Id = mshipoptions.mshipoption_Id";
```

and this is my code for getting the data to datable from database

```
string memberid;
double value = 0.0;
double expectedpayment=0.0;
double monthlypayamount=0.0;
int dueday = 0;

dt = xxxxxx.GetData(sql, mf);    
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{
      memberid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["member_Id"]).ToString();
      monthlypayamount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]);
      expectedpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[2]["ExpPayments"]);
      value = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[3]["value"]);       
}
```

but I am getting an error

> " index out of range exception"

and error like this

> "there is no row at position 1"

Would any one please help on this...

Comment: which line is the exception on? and try to find out the number of rows that you actually have by MessageBox.show(dt.rows.Count.ToString());

Comment: What exception are you getting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use index [0] for Rows on every line of code if you want to get all the data from the first row that was returned.  If you use Rows[1] and Rows[2] etc., then you are looking at the second row, and third row, etc., which is invalid if your query only returned one row of data.

Comment: you are assuming there is only ever one row in the result

Comment: @jaywayco Not really -- notice how I qualified the first statement with "if you want to get all the data from the first row that was returned."  The answer goes on to cover the possibility of more rows, again with a qualified "if your query only returned one row of data."

Answer (score 1):

You're checking for

```
dt.Rows.Count > 0
```

And then accessing rows 0, 1, 2, and 3, without checking if all of these rows exist. I think you've confused row numbers with columns, and should try

```
  memberid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["member_Id"]).ToString();
  monthlypayamount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["monthlyamount"]);
  expectedpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["ExpPayments"]);
  value = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["value"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)
{

  memberid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["member_Id"]).ToString();

  monthlypayamount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]);
  expectedpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[2]["ExpPayments"]);
  value = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[3]["value"]);       
}
```

Your if statement is only checking for the existence of 1 or more rows. However, when you set `monthlypayamount` you are assuming a second row (`dt.Rows[1]["monthlyamount"]`). I think you need to use a foreach loop to iterate the results

```
foreach(DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
   memberid = Convert.ToInt32(row["member_Id"]).ToString();
   monthlypayamount = Convert.ToDouble(row["monthlyamount"]);
   expectedpayment = Convert.ToDouble(row["ExpPayments"]);
   value = Convert.ToDouble(row["value"]);

   //logic here to use variable values before moving to next row
}
```

This will make sure you get access to all rows

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to access `row 1` however, `row 1` doesn't exist. So, it seems that your query is returning only one row that is `row 0`. Try

```
   if (dt != null && dt.Rows.Count > 0)     
{        
memberid = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["member_Id"]).ToString();        
monthlypayamount = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["monthlyamount"]);       
expectedpayment = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["ExpPayments"]);       
value = Convert.ToDouble(dt.Rows[0]["value"]);            
}
```